# Tomcat images are not rendered

Tags: tomcat, filter, java-ee-6

Actually, what is the problem, I wrote a WebFilter class that filters requests.

Here is that class:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
        if(path.startsWith("/login") || path.startsWith("/images") ||
                path.startsWith("/registration") || path.startsWith("/rest")){
            System.out.println(request.getSession(false));
            System.out.println(path + " from if expression");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }


        String email = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("email");
        if (email == null){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/login-page.jsp").forward(request, response);
            System.out.println(path + " попал в session == null");
        }else {
            System.out.println(path + " попал в session != null");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

There a problem, when I go to any page with images, I see in the console:

```
/images/logout_button.png from if expression
/images/my_tasks_button.png from if expression
/images/developer_info_button.png from if expression
```

That is, the filter passes images, but they are not rendered. Here is the project on github: https://github.com/MatveyAndrosyukk/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.

Comment: What do the browser tools tell you?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I just get 500 error

Comment: Then there is a Tomcat error log.  This is normally in the Tomcat install directory under `logs/catalina.out`.  You'll need to dig into that.